# What are the uses and benefits of get_query_set() and get_context_data()? Can we use both of them together inside a view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I was going through Django documentations and I encountered two methods of showing object's data. I am wondering if we can use both `get_query_set()` and `get_context_data` inside a single view. For example if I have 3 models named `Publisher, Books, Author` where `Books` and `Author` are related to each other with `ManyToMany` field and `Books` and `Publisher` are related via `ForeignKey`.

There is a view

```
           template_name='some_name.html'
```

There are 2 methods of showing data via getting the objects.

```
       self.Publisher=get_object_or_404(Publisher,name=self.kwargs('name_of_publisher')

            return Books.objects.filter(publisher=self.publisher)
```

I think it will return all the Book objects that are related to `name_of_publisher`. I want to ask how the data will be displayed? Will there be a loop in templates? How will the Url look like and if there is no `context` defined then how will it show data?

2nd method I came across is

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['publisher']=self.publisher
    return context
```

I found the working of this one very confusing. I am unable to understand how is this working here. I have read another posts too here just in case you'll try to give me a link. Thanks for that in advance. But what I know is can both of these be used inside a single `template` and `ListView`? If yes, Please describe how a `template` file would look like.

Answer (score 0):

`get_context_data()` prepares data for the context dictionary. If you need to add custom data, then override the way you've already done.

`get_queryset()` prepares the data that is to be displayed in the template. The return value of `get_queryset()` will be used for 'object_list' key in context dictionary. You can override the get_queryset() method to filter data based on your desired condition. So, to access the data in template file, include the following in your template file:

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    <li>{{ item.field1 }} - {{ item.field2 }} - {{ item.field2 }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```